# Flutter run url from default browser using url_launcher

Tags: flutter, url-launcher

I'm using [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) (6.1.5) and I want open the urls in default browser instead of in-app webView.

It seems that the latest version does not support it, since [launch](https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/url_launcher/launch.html) function is deprecated, and [launchUrl](https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/url_launcher/launchUrl.html) does not support the `forceWebView=false` flag.

**How do I run my url on default browser using `url_launcher`?**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### TL;DR

You can use the `LaunchMode.externalApplication` parameter.

```
await launchUrl(_url, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
```

### More info

By default the `mode` value is set to `LaunchMode.platformDefault`, which in most cases is an `inAppWebView`.

Changing the `mode` solved this issue:

```
Future<void> openUrl(String url) async {
  final _url = Uri.parse(url);
  if (!await launchUrl(_url, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication)) { // <--
    throw Exception('Could not launch $_url');
  }
}
```

`LaunchMode` support several arguments:

```
enum LaunchMode {
  /// Leaves the decision of how to launch the URL to the platform
  /// implementation.
  platformDefault,

  /// Loads the URL in an in-app web view (e.g., Safari View Controller).
  inAppWebView,

  /// Passes the URL to the OS to be handled by another application.
  externalApplication,

  /// Passes the URL to the OS to be handled by another non-browser application.
  externalNonBrowserApplication,
}
```